# .htaccess not working properly in apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have battling with this error for a while now. 
I have read and done exactly what i find in most explanations.

My Problem

i have .htaccess configured.
www.localhost/site_folder/home -- Working Fine
www.localhost/site_folder/my-profile -- Auto page to redirect After logging in works fine too
www.localhost/site_folder/any_other_link returns error page.

What i have done to check.
I have written gibberish in .htaccess. 
I got an error 500 .. Which is good showing that apache is looking into the file.

I have set AllowOveride All in /etc/apache2/apache.conf
I have mod_rewrite enabled.

Please what exactly can i do to fix this ...

```
.htaccess file


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/([^/\.]+)?$ login.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^login([^/\.]+)?$ login.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/\.]+)?$ home.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^home([^/\.]+)?$ home.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^location-report/([^/\.]+)?$ location-report.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^location-report([^/\.]+)?$ location-report.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-location/([^/\.]+)?$ new-location.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-location([^/\.]+)?$ new-location.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-location/([^/\.]+)?$ view-location.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-location([^/\.]+)?$ view-location.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-location/([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-location.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-location([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-location.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^customer-check/([^/\.]+)?$ customer-check.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^customer-check([^/\.]+)?$ customer-check.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-bonus/([^/\.]+)?$ new-bonus.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-bonus([^/\.]+)?$ new-bonus.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-topup/([^/\.]+)?$ new-topup.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-topup([^/\.]+)?$ new-topup.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-transaction/([^/\.]+)/?$ new-transaction.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-transaction([^/\.]+)?$ new-transaction.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-transaction/([^/\.]+)/?$ view-transaction.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-transaction([^/\.]+)?$ view-transaction.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-stock/([^/\.]+)?$ new-stock.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-stock([^/\.]+)?$ new-stock.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-stock/([^/\.]+)/?$ view-stock.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-stock([^/\.]+)?$ view-stock.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^update-stock/([^/\.]+)?$ update-stock.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^update-stock([^/\.]+)?$ update-stock.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^report/([^/\.]+)/?$ report.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^report([^/\.]+)?$ report.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-expenses/([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-expenses([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-expenses/([^/\.]+)?$ new-expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-expenses([^/\.]+)?$ new-expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^expenses-category/([^/\.]+)?$ expenses-category.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^expenses-category([^/\.]+)?$ expenses-category.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-expenses/([^/\.]+)?$ view-expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-expenses([^/\.]+)?$ view-expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^expenses/([^/\.]+)?$ expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^expenses([^/\.]+)?$ expenses.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-notification/([^/\.]+)?$ view-notification.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-notification([^/\.]+)?$ view-notification.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)?$ search.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search([^/\.]+)?$ search.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^my-profile/([^/\.]+)?$ profile.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^my-profile([^/\.]+)?$ profile.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/([^/\.]+)?$ settings.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^settings([^/\.]+)?$ settings.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-staff/([^/\.]+)?$ view-staff.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-staff([^/\.]+)?$ view-staff.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^staff-profile/([^/\.]+)?$ staff_profile.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^staff-profile([^/\.]+)?$ staff_profile.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-customer/([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-customer([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-staff/([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-staff.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-staff([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-staff.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-top-customer/([^/\.]+)?$ view-top-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-top-customer([^/\.]+)?$ view-top-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-receipt/([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-receipt.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-single-receipt([^/\.]+)?$ view-single-receipt.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-staff/([^/\.]+)?$ new-staff.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-staff([^/\.]+)?$ new-staff.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^print-report/([^/\.]+)?$ print-report.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^print-report([^/\.]+)?$ print-report.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^print-excel/([^/\.]+)?$ print-excel.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^print-excel([^/\.]+)?$ print-excel.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^refund/([^/\.]+)?$ refund.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^refund([^/\.]+)?$ refund.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-customer/([^/\.]+)?$ new-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-customer([^/\.]+)?$ new-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-customer/([^/\.]+)?$ view-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-customer([^/\.]+)?$ view-customer.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-membership/([^/\.]+)?$ new-membership.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-membership([^/\.]+)?$ new-membership.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-receipt/([^/\.]+)?$ view-receipt.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-receipt([^/\.]+)?$ view-receipt.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-membership/([^/\.]+)?$ view-membership.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-membership([^/\.]+)?$ view-membership.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-service/([^/\.]+)?$ new-service.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-service([^/\.]+)?$ new-service.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^general-settings/([^/\.]+)?$ general-settings.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^general-settings([^/\.]+)?$ general-settings.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^barcode-printout/([^/\.]+)?$ barcode-printout.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^barcode-printout([^/\.]+)?$ barcode-printout.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^barcode/([^/\.]+)?$ barcode.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^barcode([^/\.]+)?$ barcode.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-service/([^/\.]+)?$ view-service.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-service([^/\.]+)?$ view-service.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-task/([^/\.]+)?$ new-task.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new-task([^/\.]+)?$ new-task.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-task/([^/\.]+)?$ view-task.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view-task([^/\.]+)?$ view-task.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fresh-items/([^/\.]+)?$ fresh-items.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fresh-items([^/\.]+)?$ fresh-items.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^inventory/([^/\.]+)?$ inventory.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^inventory([^/\.]+)?$ inventory.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^print-2/([^/\.]+)?$ print-2.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^print-2([^/\.]+)?$ print-2.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You should start by posting the contents of your htaccess file in your question. It's hard to find issues with it we don't know what it looks like.

Comment: _"returns error page"_ - What does that error page say? Error message? I would probably recommend using a router instead of putting all the rules like that. Easier to maintain and add logic to it.

Comment: error 400 page not found.

Comment: Status code [400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#400) means "Bad request", if it is really "Not found" it would be a [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#404)

Comment: Well, sounds stupid.... I just did a system reset, and voilla .. everything is working